# Sort gets stuck on "ending"

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click <kbd>bounties</kbd> in the show tab
2. Click <kbd>ending</kbd> in the sort tab
3. Click <kbd>all</kbd> in the show tab

Result:

1. The sort tab still shows "ending" and it isn't seen in the drop down list:

   [image: SCREENSHOT]
2. There are two options ("all" and "bounties") in the show tab that doesn't make any difference.

Comment: By stuck you don't mean that it can't leave `sort:ending`, right?  You just mean it stays on ending when it doesn't make sense any more.

Comment: "*You just mean it stays on ending when it doesn't make sense any more*" -- Yes. I can leave "ending" if I press any other option from the drop down menu, though.

Comment: Gotcha.  "Stuck" meant initially to me "can't leave", but it makes sense.

Comment: @Joe , Please edit the question if it seems unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed and is being deployed.